# Prisma - How to push item to a list of foreign objects

Tags: orm, prisma

I am using mongodb v5.0.13

```
//schema.prisma

model Video {
  id          Int    @id @map("_id")
  title       String
  description String
  tags        Tag[]
}

model Tag {
  id          String  @id @map("_id")
  video       Video?  @relation(fields: [videoId], references: [id])
  videoId     Int?
}
```

I want to be able to add tags to a video record.

```js
//index.ts

  await prisma.video.create({
      data: {
        id: 1,
        description: "",
        title: "Dancing Cats",
      },
    });

  let tag = {id: "funny"};

  await prisma.tag.create({
      data: tag,
    });

  await prisma.video.update({
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
    data: {
      tags: {
        push: tag,
      },
    },
  });
```

I get this error whenever I run the update:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ push: Tag | null; }' is not assignable to type 'TagUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutVideoNestedInput | TagUpdateManyWithoutVideoNestedInput | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'push' does not exist in type 'TagUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutVideoNestedInput | TagUpdateManyWithoutVideoNestedInput'.

38         push: tag,
           ~~~~~~~~~
```

The code using the mongodb driver is not much different(syntax wise) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```js
  await prisma.video.create({
      data: {
        id: 1,
        description: "",
        title: "Dancing Cats",
      },
    });

  let tag = {id: "funny"};

  const newTag = await prisma.tag.create({
      data: tag,
    });

  await prisma.video.update({
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
    data: {
      tags: {
        push: newTag,
      },
    },
  });
```

?